# //initialize a new INTSTK pointed by p which can store at most m ntegers

Tags: c++

```
struct INTSTK{
    int  *const e;      //points to memory allocated to store integers
    const int  m;       //maximum number of integers the stack can holds
    int   t;            //top indicator or number of integers in the stack;

void initSTK (INTSTK *const p, int m); 
};
```

I need help in the definition of the initSTK function
void initSTK(INTSTK *const p, int m)
{
//initialize a new INTSTK pointed by p which can store at most m ntegers

}

Comment: what's your question? I mean what is the problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Why not use [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

Comment: i tried write definition of the function initSTK (INTSTK *const p, int m) but it didn't work. would you help me pls?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify `const` member variables anywhere else but in construction.

Try this:

```
struct INTSTK{
    int  *const e;      //points to memory allocated to store integers
    const int  m;       //maximum number of integers the stack can holds
    int   t;            //top indicator or number of integers in the stack;

    INTSTK(int m_) : e(new int[m_]), m(m_), t(0) {}
};

void initSTK (INTSTK *const p, int m) {
    // assuming input is already populated with type `INTSTK *const`                                                                                                                 
    new (p) INTSTK(m);
}
```

Comment: thank you for help. can you help me in defining void initSTK (INTSTK *const p, int m);   //initialize a new INTSTK pointed by p which can store at most m ntegers

Comment: @Hagos Done. It does assume that the memory pointed has already been allocated though.